# ag-grid how do I set the floating filter height

Tags: javascript, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

Anyone know how to set the floating filter height?

I have looked through all the documentation and I can't see anything.  The next thing I am looking at is tweaking the theme.  But so far no luck there either.

I looked at the css in dev tools and found that it didn't have a class I could style.   The tag has a manual style applied to it.

```
<div class="ag-header-row" role="presentation" 
style="top: 30px;height: 56px;width: 1603px;">
```

So I don't believe I can't hack it with a class or a template override.  Anyone else know how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be achieved using `gridOptions.floatingFiltersHeight` config.
Here is an [example](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-column-header/#example-text-orientation) from ag grid documentation.

As per docs-

> floatingFiltersHeight -   The height for the row containing the floating
>   filters. If not specified the default is 20px.

Answer (score 1):

we can apply directly apply in `<AgGridReact>` tag, `floatingFiltersHeight={20}` as property in the following way

```
<AgGridReact
   rowStyle={rowStyle}
   ref={gridRef}
   columnDefs={columnDefs}
   rowData={rowData}
   headerHeight={20}
   rowHeight={20}
   floatingFiltersHeight={20} // floatingFiltersHeight applied
   defaultColDef={defaultColDef}
   onGridReady={onGridReady}
   onFilterChanged={()=> setRow(gridRef.current.gridOptions.api.getDisplayedRowCount())}
></AgGridReact>
```